# How to find only dirty object without iterating items in an ObjectStore of EnhancedGrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Is there any way to get  only dirty object without iterating items in an ObjectStore of EnhancedGrid?

Comment: grid.store._dirtyObjects?

Comment: Thanks Kirill, it is working. Can you please update it as resolution.

Comment: Glad to help. I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it with `grid.store._dirtyObjects`